# HTTP server not receiving HTTP request from Android app using Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I have an HTTP server on my Raspberry Pi and it toggles GPIO pins on/off based on incoming queries. Sending HTTP requests from my browser works fine, but now I'm trying to implement it in an Android app. Looking at my server logs on the Raspberry Pi I don't see any requests from this app, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I was just trying to get the most simple example possible working before making it any more complicated but I'm having issues even with that.

Can I do it all in the main activity like I'm trying to do here? Or do I need to create a separate activity just for sending the HTTP request? What am I doing terribly wrong?

EDIT: I added some logging and see I'm getting the following in logcat with each button press:

```
05-14 22:37:00.777      461-461/com.example.jeff.myapp D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
05-14 22:37:00.857      461-479/com.example.jeff.myapp I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-14 22:37:00.877      461-479/com.example.jeff.myapp I/System.out﹕ KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
05-14 22:37:00.947      461-461/com.example.jeff.myapp V/Volley Error﹕ com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I've tried adding all the permissions below to my manifest, but none have solved the EACCES permission error.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

If I change the url to "http://www.google.com/" I see the following error in logcat:

```
05-14 22:50:29.647  13086-13112/com.example.jeff.myapp E/Volley﹕ [38866] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:367)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:295)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:500)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
     Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:367)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:295)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:500)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:367)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:295)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:500)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private RequestQueue mVolleyQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mVolleyQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Toggle button */
    public void toggleGPIO(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toggle GPIO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String url = "http://192.168.1.17:8080/gpio?pin=0&value=1";

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.v("onResponse", response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.v("Volley Error", error.toString());
            }
        });

        mVolleyQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information to tell the problem. Could you use the `Log` class to generate some debug messages at places like inside `onReponse()` and `onErrorResponse()` and post the logcat?

Comment: Where in your manifest are you placing your permissions? Can you copy paste your manifest?

Comment: Can you post the whole manifest ?

Comment: Yep, I just realized that was the problem...permission was in the wrong place in the manifest...stupid me. Thanks all